# Можно ли менять текст в табл./блоках? docx py

Tags: python, python-docx

Делаю скрипт для замены слов в документе, и столкнулся с такой проблемой как скрипт не меняет слова в некоторых участках.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую библиотеку docx на питоне. Как все же менять слова в этих таблицах/блоках, решения я так и не нашел.

Есть ли какие-нибудь альтернативные библиотеки или иные способы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У объектов `Document` есть атрибут [tables](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document.tables), который представляет собой список таблиц в документе.

Как и сказано в документации, в этом списке представлены только таблицы "верхнего" уровня. (То есть если у вас есть вложенная таблица внутри ячейки таблицы, по ней надо тоже пройтись)

Внутри [таблицы](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html#docx.table.Table) можно пройтись по ее строкам - [rows](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html#docx.table.Table.rows), в каждом из которых можно пройтись по его ячейкам - [cells](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html#docx.table._Row.cells).

Ну а в ячейках уже есть text и tables.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Все работает